# Processing a list of async calls to a C# library, in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have the following code:

```
    let results =
        instruments
        |> List.map    (fun i -> getBinanceSymbolFromInstrument i)
        |> List.map    (fun i -> restClient.CancelAllOrders (i) )
        |> List.filter (fun r -> not r.Success)
        |> List.fold   (fun acc m -> (m.Error.Code, (sprintf "%s\n%i - %s" (snd acc) m.Error.Code m.Error.Message))) (0, String.Empty)
```

essentially, it takes a list of identifiers, converts them, call a C# lib (restClient.CancelAllOrders (i)) and then make a list of the calls that failed.

I would like to modify this to use the async version of the call:

the C# function is defined as:

```
public async Task<WebCallResult<BinanceFuturesCancelAllOrders>> CancelAllOrdersAsync(string symbol, long? receiveWindow = null, CancellationToken ct = default)
```

and what I would like to do is be able to do all the calls to the CancelAllOrdersAsync method in parallel (the order is irrelevant, but latency matters) and then gather the results like it is currently done.

How can this be achieved in F#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Async.Parallel` primitive to do this. The operation takes a sequence of asynchronous operations and creates a new asynchronous operation that returns an array of results of the individual operations:

```
Async.Parallel : seq<Async<'a>> -> Async<'a []>
```

In your case, you already have a list, so you can invoke the asynchronous version and obtain a list of type `list<Async<...>>` Then you can turn this into a single `Async<...>` producing an array of results. If you do not mind blocking at the top-level, you can then use `Async.RunSynchronously` and you get an array of results.

I was not able to run your code, but something like this should work:

```
let results =
  instruments
  |> List.map (fun i -> getBinanceSymbolFromInstrument i)
  |> List.map (fun i -> 
       restClient.CancelAllOrdersAsync (i)
       |> Async.AwaitTask)
  |> Async.Parallel
  |> Async.RunSynchronously
  |> List.ofArray
  |> List.filter (fun r -> not r.Success)
  |> List.fold (fun acc m -> 
       m.Error.Code, 
       sprintf "%s\n%i - %s" (snd acc) m.Error.Code m.Error.Message)) (0, String.Empty)
```

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, the Async.Await task in the map returns a list of awaiters, the runSynchronously executes everything in the list, but what about Async.Parallel? does it just transform the type of the list so that it is recognized as a list of tasks with awaiters?

Comment: You are correct about `AwaitTask` - it turns `Task<'T>` into `Async<'T>`. The `Async.Parallel` operation is explained in my answer - it creates a computation that starts all computations in a given list and collects the results and then completes.

Comment: so the execution is done at `Async.Parallel` but not at `Async.RunSynchronously`? then what is the role os the `Async.RunSynchronously`? is it like Thread.Join?

Comment: `Async.Parallel` takes a list of (not yet running) computations and produces a new (not yet running) computation that, when started, starts them all in parallel. `Async.RunSynchronously` actually starts this composed computation and waits for the result.